# Google Sheet - Compound FV on a SPECIFIC DATE

Tags: google-sheets-formula, finance

I got a basic issue looking like voodoo magic to me (a noob at google sheet):

**What I need (a future value on a specific date)**

Instead of the usual Future Value after "n" years or months I need to know the future value on a SPECIFIC DATE (eg.: on the 20th of March 2030 or in "2560" days) compounded either yearly or monthly with or without contribution.

**What I have (the usual data for calculating FV):**

- Yearly (or monthly if it's easier) compound rate.
- A present principal which compounds yearly or monthly
- A regular monthly (or weekly) contribution to the principal.

**SAMPLE FORMULAS I WORK WITH:**

FV = SV*(((CAGR*100)/100)+1)^n.

FV - Future Value
SV - Starting Value
CAGR - Compound Annual Growth Rate
n - years

This tells me how much capital I will have given an annual growth rate after n years. But how to have the formula telling me what that capital will be on a specific date and also how to add the monthly/weekly contribution?

Any idea on how to achieve this?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Please provide a sample sheet and/or sample data. Expected output would be good to have too. If you want to calculate a date difference, you can use  `=DATEDIF(TODAY(),DATE(2030,3,20),"M")`, where `"M"` means months.

Comment: Hi sure, given this formula for example:
FV = SV*(((CAGR*100)/100)+1)^n. And given the variables                                                               





FV - Future Value

SV - Starting Value

CAGR - Compound Annual Growth Rate

n - years

This tells me how much capital I will have given an annual growth rate after n years.
But how to have the formula telling me what that capital will be on a specific date and also how to add the monthly/weekly contribution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I created a calculator in Google Sheets that has all the necessary formulas for FV, PV, PVAF, and "Compound FV on a SPECIFIC DATE".**

Although, I believe this question is more suited to the [Personal Finance & Money](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions) and Stackexchange site.

**See this [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UdWpkbUO9Y-tQtWp7hOEF9Sgt-MMMgH1ZSlIhuKQfBo/edit#gid=0) for the calculator.**

[image]

**Description**

In order to calculate the contributions into the formula we must use the following values:

```
p = initial value
n = compounding periods per year
r = nominal interest rate, compounded n times per year
i = periodic interest rate = r/n
y = number of years
t = number of compounding periods = n*y
d = periodic deposit
```

The formula for the future value of an annuity due is

```
d*(((1 + i)^t - 1)/i)*(1 + i)
```

(In an annuity due, a deposit is made at the beginning of a period and the interest is received at the end of the period. This is in contrast to an ordinary annuity, where a payment is made at the end of a period.)

The formula is derived, by induction, from the summation of the future values of every deposit.

[image]

The initial value, with interest accumulated for all periods, can simply be added.

```
pfv = p*(1 + i)^t

total = pfv + fv
```

So the overall formula is

[image]

Comment: Hey Daniel it's great thanks but still the challenge of calculating the future value compounded yearly on a specific date is not resolved :).

Comment: Hello, I have added a formula to it that will calculate the required "t" value based on the end date (start date is set to automatically show the day that you view the spreadsheet on with the TODAY formula). Just change the END date and use the given "t" value in the calculator (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UdWpkbUO9Y-tQtWp7hOEF9Sgt-MMMgH1ZSlIhuKQfBo/edit#gid=0)

Comment: How would you add a monthly, weekly contribution to the calculator though? FV of capital, with monthly contribution?

Comment: Daniel amazingly helpful, generous and ...genius! Thanks a lot and hopefully this helps many others

Comment: I marked this as answered although I reckoned it could be interesting to point out the calculator gives different results when compared to another calculator such as https://www.thecalculatorsite.com/finance/calculators/compoundinterestcalculator.php

Comment: You are most welcome! Thank you for pointing that out, I will take another look at my calculator and see if I've missed something.

Comment: @rudyStock I got the same results with the numbers currently in the calculator and here (https://www.thecalculatorsite.com/compound?a=1000&p=5&pp=yearly&y=1&m=1&rd=100&rp=monthly&rt=deposit&rm=end&ci=monthly&ip=&c=1&di=2)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231363/discussion-between-rudystock-and-daniel-h).